# Carthage xcodebuild timed out

Tags: xcode, frameworks, carthage

I tried to create a Carthage framework using v0.23.0 and Xcode 8.3.3.
When I ran the command "carthage build --no-skip-current", it led to the following error message: 
"*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/h4/1slt67613tx6c_xdd4ffp9nw0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.mOvSot.log
xcodebuild timed out while trying to read
"

Here is my machine's settings:

xcrun version 32.

Xcode command line tool version:
xcode-select version 2347.

xcodebuild -version:
Xcode 8.3.3
Build version 8E3004b

Carthage version:
0.23.0

Please advise.

Thank you,
Helen

Comment: I cleaned this folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData as some people had suggested.  It is still not working.

Comment: Project Scheme is shared though.

Comment: I also cleaned these 3 caches folders:                                  ~/Library/Caches/carthage,  
~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.carthage, ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem when I switched to Xcode 9.

After a carthage build or update the following message came up.

> xcodebuild timed out while trying to read AWSiOSSDKv2.xcodeproj

I tried to open the xcodeprok using Xcode, close Xcode and then rerun carthage build. The problem was gone.

I believe that it has to do with something that was missing and added once i opened the project in Xcode.

After carthage update I have to reopen the xcode project that timed out and rerun carthage build this time.

Comment: As this problem was similar, but not the same with mine I created a new question and answered it. It can be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072080/carthage-xcode-9-xcodebuild-timed-out-while-trying-to-read-xcodeproj-error/46072081#46072081