# Carthage, Xcode 9. "xcodebuild timed out while trying to read *.xcodeproj" error

Tags: ios, xcode, aws-sdk, carthage, xcode9

Today I downloaded xCode 9 and started converting everything to Swift 3.2/4, so I can build and run my project.

As it was expected carthage complaint about some project that they could not be build, as they were not compatible with Swift 3.2/4. I had to find the versions that were compatible and build them.

I also had to use --no-use-binaries, as some frameworks are precompiled with previous versions of Swift.

I then got the following error:

> xcodebuild timeout while trying to read AWSiOSSDKv2.xcodeproj

So far I was probably not getting this error, as i was downloading AWS framework precompiled. Now that carthage had to compile it locally, something was missing and was creating the timeout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To sort it out I did the following steps:

- Open the timed out project in Xcode
- Do not do anything
- Run "Carthage build --platform iOS"

Everything compiled without any errors. It seams that once the project is opened in Xcode, Xcode is automatically adding something that is missing and the project compiles then.

This process has to be followed after every "carthage update", as the update will download a fresh xcode project.

Comment: Thanks, worked well for me. I think in my case it need to load Swift Package Dependencies

Comment: In our case it looked like it was verifying the simulator runtimes and somehow timed out when doing that through carthage without ever making any progress.